# How to force RCP to reload the table content

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have this huge RCP enterprise CRM system I'm working on. Last year it was updated to RCP 4.5. Sadly I'm very bad with RCP because I never had to do with the frontend of it... So my question might seem a little bit strange.

Anyways, my problem is:

I have one table window where all the rows all filled up correctly with data. One column has a function, where I can double click on and one other window will open, where I can edit/remove/add data to it. The IDs of the added values are then showing in the main window's table column. (this is working correctly)

The problem: If I open this editor window, edit something (add new values or remove one or more), then click save and close this edit window (it's actually a new tab...) and then going back to this window after the editing, it will show me the state BEFORE the editing... (new values are not in the list, removed one are still on the list) The values are correctly stored or deleted in the DB, only the UI seems to stuck with the old state. I have to restart the GUI if I want to see the correct (and the actual) state.

My question: how can I force RCP to forget the old state for this tab/window and load the data everytime from DB? I tried many things in the saving method of this window (refresh, dispose of), but nothing seems to work...

Comment: You haven't told us enough about how the code works to say anything.

Comment: Well, sadly I don't know what exactly should I tell about this code? Can you help me out? As I said I'm not an expert in RCP

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a `TableViewer` or so?. using the `tableViewer.setInput(...)`  again with new data + `layout()` may solve the problem, buit as @greg-449 said, we need for information on what kind of taale you are using to display your data and how you tell that table where is this data...

Comment: Well, all I could find, that this is a scrolledComposite... Sounds this somehow relevant? :)

Comment: No. You must have a `TableViewer` or so too display your data in some. way. a `scrollComposite is just an artefact to allow to show horizontal or vertical scrollbars. You shouls show us some code if you want more help

Comment: Sorry, It has some corporate wrapper around it, but yeah, it's a TableViewer, you are right!